# Need Help Regarding AWS SNS Message Retries

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

How do I add message retry policies in my SNS subscription? I read some documentation and I think it is the deliveryPolicy but how do I implement it in my cloudformation code below.

```
  ResPartnerSubscription:
DependsOn:
  - ResPartnerTopic
Type: AWS::SNS::Subscription
Properties:
  TopicArn: !Ref ResPartnerTopic
  Protocol: lambda
  Endpoint: !GetAtt ProgramDeviceSyncSns.Arn
  RedrivePolicy:
    deadLetterTargetArn: !GetAtt DeadLetterQueue.Arn
```

I have read documentation where people have said that only Http/s protocols can use deliveryPolicy for message retries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change retry policies for `lambda` endpoint as they are fixed and listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-delivery-retries.html#delivery-policies-for-protocols).

The retry policies can be customized only for [HTTP/S](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-delivery-retries.html#creating-delivery-policy) endpoints.